# Bubble Sort in NASM Ubuntu

Tags: sorting, ubuntu, assembly, nasm, bubble-sort

I was asked to create a bubble sort program in NASM Ubuntu. Here's the code:

```
section .data
i           db 0                    ; Value to be incremented
question    db  'Enter a number: '  ; Prompt
questionLen equ $-question
newLine     db 10, 10, 0            ; New blank line
newLineLen  equ $-newLine

section .bss
num resb 5          ; Array of size 5
counter resb 1      ; Value to be incremented
counter2 resb 1     ; Value to be incremented
temp resb 1
temp2 resb 1

section .text
global _start

_start:
mov esi, 0

getInput:
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, question           ; Prints the question
mov edx, questionLen
int 80h

add byte[i], 30h            ; I'll retain this expression, since the program experienced an error
                                ; when this expression is deleted
sub byte[i], 30h            ; Converts the increment value to integer

mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
lea ecx, [num + esi]        ; Element of the array
mov edx, 2
int 80h

inc esi
inc byte[i]
cmp byte[i], 5              ; As long as the array hasn't reached the size of 5,
jl getInput                 ; the program continues to ask input from the user

mov esi, 0
mov byte[i], 0
mov edi, 0                  ; Index of the array

bubble_sort:
mov byte[counter], 0
mov byte[counter2], 0

begin_for_1:
    mov al, 0
    mov al, [counter]       ; Acts as the outer for loop
    cmp al, 5
    jg printArray           ; Prints the sorted list when the array size has reached 5
begin_for_2:
    mov edi, [counter2] ; Acts as the inner for loop
    cmp edi, 4
    jg end_for_2
    mov bl, 0               ; Acts as the if statement
    mov cl, 0
    mov bl, [num + edi]
    mov cl, [num + edi + 1]
    mov byte[temp], cl  ; This is the same as if(a[j] > a[j + 1]){...}
    cmp bl, [temp]
    jg bubbleSortSwap
return:
    inc edi                 ; Same as j++
    jmp begin_for_2     ; Goes out of the inner for loop
end_for_2:
    inc byte[counter]       ; Same as i++
    jmp begin_for_1     ; Goes out of the outer for loop

bubbleSortSwap:
mov [num + edi + 1], bl
mov [num + edi], cl     ; The set of statements is the same as swap(&a[j], &a[j + 1]);
jmp return

printArray:
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, [num + esi]        ; Prints one element at a time
mov edx, 1
int 80h

inc esi
inc byte[i]
cmp byte[i], 5
jl printArray               ; As long as the array size hasn't reached 5, printing continues

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, newLine            ; Displays a new blank line after the array
mov edx, newLineLen
int 80h

mov eax, 1                  ; Exits the program
mov ebx, 0
int 80h
```

But the only problem is, it cannot print the rest of the iterations, because it only prints the 1st iteration like this:

```
Enter a number: 7
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: 3
Enter a number: 5
17435
```

What I want to output is the array input and the final output, from the 1st iteration up to the last.

Answer (score 0):

Naw... he just needs some stuff sorted! :)

Doesn't print any output at all for me, as posted. Problem is you're putting "[contents]" in ecx - you want address - you do it right in the input routine.

You can get by with fewer variables - use esi and/or edi as both the "count" and the "index". If you use variables, make sure the size of the variable matches the size of the register you're moving it in/out of! ("mov edi, [counter2]" isn't doing what you want) Courage! If it wuz easy, everybody'd be doing it.

Best,
Frank